# Looping through 3 million elements of a list to 'Set' values is slow

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, assignment

I am looping through the 3 million elements of a time-series (v1, o1) and corresponding values (v2, o2).

- v1 contains a uniformly increasing timestamp (e.g. 1 to 3,000,000 in increments of 1)
- o1 contains a non-uniformly increasing timestamp (includes gaps, meaning o1 is a shorter list)
- v2 contains zeroes
- o2 contains real-type values

The purpose is to assign the o2 values to v2 for each v1 timestamp. In case of a gap, a previous o2 value will be used.

Could this code be optimized?

Sample input

```
 v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
 o1 = {2, 3, 5}
 v2 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 o2 = {0.3, 0.5, 0.1}
```

Sample output

```
 v2 = {0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1}
```

Code

```
v1 = Range[1, 3000000, 1];
v2 = ConstantArray[0., 3000000];
o1 = Delete[v1, {#} & /@ RandomInteger[3000000, 500000]];
o2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[o1]];

Length[o1]
Length[v1]

y = 1;
i = 1;                              (* Revision: Set i to 1 *)
  Monitor[
    While[i<Length[v1],             (* Revision: substitute Do for While *)
      If[SameQ[v1[[i]], o1[[y]]],
        v2[[i]] = o2[[y]];
        i++;                     (* Revision: i++ *)
        y++,
        If[v1[[i]] < o1[[y]],
          v2[[i]] = o2[[y - 1]];
          i++,                   (* Revision: i++ *)
          y++]]
    ], {i, y}] // Timing
```

Big thank-you to all the participants emphasizing the importance of clear problem formulation, as well as providing with inputs, and expected outputs.

Comment: Can you please provide some example data or a procedure to generate simulated data.

Comment: Don't do it that way - mutating a step at a time is... slow. Make a zero list of correct length. Populate the indices at o1 *with* o1. Fold Max over that. Use result to pull values. All are one-step operations, should handle millions of entries in a fraction of a second...

Comment: @ciao Are you assuming `o2` is increasing?

Comment: @belisarius: you mean `o1`? Then yes - it's time steps, so unless we're back to the future... if you meant `o2` - not sure what you mean, it's just data values from my read.

Comment: @ciao I've read `o2`. Silly me

Comment: @Matvei Kruglyak - The code you have supplied doesn't run because the `y` variable has no initial value. I guess you want it to start at 1?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Yes, I noticed the same problem. Actually OP should clarify what is the exact output expected. Let's take a very simple example: `v1 = Range[10]; v2 = ConstantArray[0, 10]; o1 = {3, 7}; o2 = {11, 22}`. OP code returns: `{List, List, 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 0, 0, 0}` (which shows the problem at the beginning of the list). BUT, what exactly does the OP want: 1/ `{0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 0, 0, 0}`, 2/ `{0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 22}`, something else ...? I found few other solutions, one in particular with (it seems) a big improvement.I'll post when the [hold] is released ;).

Comment: There are still some a few problems: your sample output `v2 = {0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0}` 1/ doesn't match at all the output of your code : `{List, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0}`, and 2/ doesn't match what you say "In case of a gap, a previous o2 value will be used" : that is to say that for example for timestamp=4 (gap) the corresponding value should be the same than for timestamp=3, that is 0.5 and not 0.1 ! Please correct your post.

Comment: Also as performance is clearly the goal of your post, you should definitely accept the answer with the fastest solution, that is Ciao's !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now that OP has accepted an answer, implicitly making the results from it correct, here's a *much* faster method than the fastest there (as in 3x to nearly order of magnitude faster, depending on amount of missing points):

```
v2 = c2 = ConstantArray[0, Length@v1];
v2[[o1]] = o2;
c2[[o1]] = o1;
c2[[Range[1, First@o1]]] = Range[1, First@o1];
v2 = v2[[With[{xx = c2}, Compile[{}, FoldList[Max, xx]]][]]];
```

Had this flash when nodding off, should be much faster still:

```
c2 = ConstantArray[0, Length@v1];
c2[[o1]] = 1;
If[c2[[1]] == 0, c2[[1]] = 1; o2 = Prepend[o2, 0]];
c2 = Accumulate@c2;
v2 = o2[[c2]];
```

Take a look at [*SquareOne*'s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/93974/11467) neat post of various methods and timings...

Comment: Faster indeed ! ;) Very instructive answer (for me at least) ! (As requested, see timings in my post).

Comment: @SquareOne: Glad you like it, give update a whirl - simpler, and much faster again in my quick tests...

Comment: @Matvei Kruglyak :appreciate the accept, glad you find answer useful. I'd humbly ask however that you return accept to SquareOne - their answer is most educational, shows effort, and they were kind enough to mention mine so if a reader has performance as top priority, they'll see mine referenced. I mark my answers as wiki so I get no points, I'd rather a deserving new poster like SquareOne get them...

Comment: Added the new faster solution to my timings. Nice ! Also I had to correct your previous timings because I forgot to include the beginning part of your code, sorry ;( However, it is only a little bit slower.

Comment: I did actually ask OP to accept your answer as performance is clearly the goal. You can mention my post for the detailed timings and comparison with other approaches.

Comment: @SquareOne: Well, up to OP, like I said, I get no points and don't care about them - I really like your post and work therein, I'd upvote it again if I could... thanks for adding new timings.

Answer (score 9):

Here are 3 other approaches.

I'll first test their output with very basic input:

```
n = 10;
o1 = {3, 7, 9}; o2 = {2.2, 3.3, 4.4}
```

*It is not clear what the OP exactly needs at the extremities of the new list: for example here do the values for time steps 1 and 2 have to be 0 or 2.2 ? Same question for time step 10 ? The different approaches below show some differences regarding to this, but they could be easily adapted.*

**TimeSeries**

```
Normal@Quiet@
  TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[o2, {o1}], {1, n, 1}, 
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]
```

> `{{1, 2.2}, {2, 2.2}, {3, 2.2}, {4, 2.2}, {5, 2.2}, {6, 2.2}, {7, 3.3}, {8, 3.3}, {9, 4.4}, {10, 4.4}}`

**FoldList & SparseArray**

```
(*v2 = FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #1, #2] &, Normal@SparseArray[o1 -> o2, n]]*)
v2 = FoldList[Max, Normal@SparseArray[o1 -> o2, n]]
```

> `{0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 4.4, 4.4}`

To compare to the previous result with the time series form:

```
Thread@{Range@n, v2}
```

> `{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2.2}, {4, 2.2}, {5, 2.2}, {6, 2.2}, {7, 3.3}, 
>   {8, 3.3}, {9, 4.4}, {10, 4.4}}`

**ConstantArray & Differences**

```
v2 = Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, Join @@@ {{{0}, o2}, {{First@o1 - 1}, 
 Differences@o1, {n - Last@o1 + 1}}}]
```

> {0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 4.4, 4.4}

```
Thread@{Range@n, v2}
```

> `{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2.2}, {4, 2.2}, {5, 2.2}, {6, 2.2}, {7, 3.3}, {8,3.3}, {9, 4.4}, {10, 4.4}}`

### Performance

***(Comparison of all the user's answers)***

Here are some timings on my macbook for the following parameters:

```
SeedRandom[409];
n = 3000000;
n1 = 2500000; (*and n1=500000*)
v1 = Range[n];
o1 = Union@RandomInteger[{1, n}, n1];
o2 = Reverse[o1/100 // N];
```

(Timings are in **seconds**):

[image]

**Ciao** has provided the **fastest answer** ! It's a very instructive answer as it shows how fast can be working  with `Part` and list of indices (`[[{i1,i2,...}]]`) and to always deal as much as possible with integers (`FoldList[Max,...]`).

Also, as commented below, the built-in **`TimeSeriesResample`** function is 40.4/0.3 =about **130x slower** than Ciao's ...

Comment: I don't think any of these is are the fastest possible way, but seeing as OP code is broken (or question is underspecified), moot at this point...

Comment: Innovative use of `Join`, `MapThread`, `ConstantArray` and `Differences`. I get it to be about an order of magnitude faster than the original loop method.

Comment: If you have time, please add my answer to timings - curious of results on your hardware, it is *much* faster on mine...

Comment: BTW, if you do re-test, might want to do it reflective of OP example - you have the opposite: OP keeps most of the data, you are dropping most of it - should change n1 to about 2500000 to mimic OP.... I'd venture the order of performance of the different solutions might get juggled if the OP example is followed

Comment: The interesting question is why TimeSeries is so slow. Is this a bug? Does WRI care?

Comment: @RolfMertig Yes ... I would say that unfortunately this kind of situation for built-in functions almost does not "surprise" me anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding @ciao's comment above:

```
n = 3 10^6;
n1 = 10000;
v1 = Range[n];
o1 = Union@RandomInteger[{1, n}, n1];
o2 = Reverse[ o1/1000 // N]; (*Anything*)

getV2[v1_, o1_, o2_] := Module[{f, v2},
  v2 = 0 v1;
  v2[[o1]] = o1;
  (f[#1] = #2) & @@@ Transpose[{o1, o2}];
  f[0] = o2[[1]];
  v2 = f /@ FoldList[Max, v2]
  ]

getV2[v1, o1, o2]; // Timing
```

Comment: The beauty of direct references... +1 o/c!

Comment: I don't  think this produces what the OP is asking for. I think he is asking for a zero-order interpolation.

Comment: @m_goldberg And I don´t think what you do think :) Who knows!

Comment: @m_goldberg This answer substitues the previous valid non-zero value for zero values in v2 (a direct substitution of o2 values is used).  I applied Matvei Kruglyak code to a short version of example data and it matched belisarius's result. I believe it answers the question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of this question is that the OP is asking for a zero-order interpolation of his data. There for I propose the following solution.

First a proof of concept using about 50 points based on belisarius' data model.

```
SeedRandom[42];
  Module[{interp, n, n1, o1, o2},
    n = 50;
    n1 = 15; 
    o1 = {1, Sequence @@ Union@RandomInteger[{2, n - 1}, n - n1], n}; 
    o2 = Reverse[o1/1000 // N];
    interp = Interpolation[Transpose[{o1, o2}], InterpolationOrder -> 0];
    v2 = Table[interp[i], {i, 1, n}]];

ListPlot[v2, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image: plot]

Here is timing with `3*^6` points with about 1000 gaps punched into it.

```
SeedRandom[42];
Module[{interp, n, n1, o1, o2},
  n = 3*^6;
  n1 = 1*^3; 
  o1 = {1, Sequence @@ Union@RandomInteger[{2, n - 1}, n - n1], n}; 
  o2 = Reverse[o1/1000 // N];
  Timing[
    interp = Interpolation[Transpose[{o1, o2}], InterpolationOrder -> 0]; 
    Table[interp[i], {i, 1, n}];]]
```

> ```
> {11.7651, Null}
> ```

This generate the required list about 8500 times faster than the OP's estimate of 30 elements per second.

Comment: When I make a table of a short example o1 with gaps and associated o2, it becomes apparent that rather than getting the previous value it uses the next value. Here there is a gap between 3 and 8 Table[{i, 
  Interpolation[{{1, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, 7}, {8, 2}, {9, 3}, {10, 1}}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0][i]}, {i, 1, 10}] and the result {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 7}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {7, 2}, {8, 2}, {9, 
  3}, {10, 1}} shows that 4 thru 8 are filled with 2's. Kruglyak's question asked for a previous value (check his code on a short sample). Can your answer be modified to provide that?